# What is the meaning of the __attribute__ vector_size(16)?

Tags: gcc, attributes

I got a C program were I saw the `__attribute__` keyword for the 1st time. It seems like it is a GNU keyword. In GCC's [this page](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gcc_62.html), they explain its use with the `(vector_size(16))` attribute, saying:

> > `int foo __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));`
> >
> > causes the compiler to set the mode for foo, to be 16 bytes, divided into int sized units. Assuming a 32-bit int (a vector of 4 units of 4 bytes), the corresponding mode of foo will be V4SI.

What does this mean? Is `foo` now declared as a 4-element array of ints? If so, what is wrong with just:

`int foo[4];`

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's for use with SIMD vectorization.  (No, it doesn't make `foo` an array.)

It's documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html), or in "Using Vector Instructions through Built-in Functions" section of the gcc manual (section 6.52 as of gcc 13.2.0).

Comment: Thanks. So, in some sense it is analogous to a structure of 4 int elements, for which some basic operators are overloaded. Also, if I understand it correctly, they actually say that you *can* reference the individual elements as elements of an array.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? (I see both answers have downvotes; I don't know whether the other one is recent.)

Comment: I came to correct this, couldn't. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Siamaster: How would you correct it? (I'm not too worried about it.)

Comment: Tried to upvote it instead or downvote it twice, but that didn't work. Anyways, that documentation page answers the question well.

Answer (score 0):

No, foo isn't be declared as an array. In this statement the int type specifies the base type, while the attribute specifies the vector size for the variable, measured in bytes.