# Trouble with translation of typedef between C to D

Tags: c, d

I'm new on D programming and I am trying to translate a code from C to D, the actual line that I am having trouble is

```
typedef double Vec __attribute__ ((vector_size(16)));
```

... I tried on:

```
alias Vez = double[16];
```

but it didnt work probably ... any help ?

Comment: I supose you mean `alias` with only one l ... (if not revert my editing)

Comment: I'm in a rush so don't have time for a full answer, but a `Vec` there in C is being typed `double`, so your first step will be just `alias Vec = double;`. But then that `__attribute__` stuff is for simd optimizations and I don't know how to express that in D. Maybe someone else will answer while I'm gone though. I kinda suspect the code will work without it for at least basic stuff though.

Comment: Do something along `import gcc.attribute;

@attribute("vector_size(16)")`. Note that `__attribute__` is GCC specific, compiler specific, it might be impossible to translate it to other compiler. The GNU D compiler `GDC` maybe supports the same attributes that GCC, I wonder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843597/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-attribute-vector-size16 "It's for use with SIMD vectorization. (No, it doesn't make foo an array.)"

Answer (score 3):

There's [`core.simd.Vector`](https://dlang.org/library/core/simd/vector.html) which does something similar. I'm not sure exactly what the differences are, but I'm sure there are some.

The one I know about is `Vector` takes the number of elements instead of the size in bytes, so

```
typedef double Vec __attribute__ ((vector_size(16)));
```

becomes

```
import core.simd : Vector;
alias Vec = Vector!(double[2]);
```

However, DMD only supports this for x64. It works in LDC for both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures, and I believe the same is true for GDC.